# Can anyone help identify the lens mount on this Vivitar 85 - 205 lens?

Tags: lens, zoom, vivitar

Trying to identify my copy of this classic lens.

A similar question has been [asked here previously](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/97542/what-is-the-mount-on-this-vivitar-85-205mm-f3-8-lens?newreg=0b794db729374160ae994926b4bafeaa), but my lens appears to be slightly different to that one.

It's a Vivitar 85 - 205 Auto Tele-zoom, but the serial number (22249552) appears to have one extra digit more than those referenced in the [camera wiki page](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Vivitar_85-205mm_f/3.8_Zoom) about the lens.

Basically I'm hoping to figure out what adapter I need to find to convert it to e-mount for use with a couple of different cameras (FX6 and BMPCC4K, both with focal reducers) for use in video.

Thanks so much.

[image: mount]

[image: Serial number]

[image: Aperture]

Comment: It has  a Nikon F mount just like the lens in your link. Why do you think it is not?

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Just wanted to double check, as I've never dealt with this kind of mount before! Especially as the serial number doesn't correspond to anything in the wiki (or anything I can find on Google).

There seem to be several kinds of F mount, so I'm wondering will all of [these adapters] (https://www.ebay.ie/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=nikon+f+to+ef&_sacat=0) work? Can't find any that will ship to Ireland on amazon or in local stores for a reasonable price, so riding the choppy waters of ebay.

Comment: There really is only one Nikon F mount. You just need a very basic adapter.

Comment: @MikeSowsun There can be mechanical issues with pre-AI lenses and cameras made for AI lenses within the Nikon F-mount. I would presume the same might be the case with adapters that might be made with the extra coupling receiver for AI lenses? Putting an pre-AI lens on such an adapter could cause damage and might require disassembly of one or both to get the lens and adapter uncoupled from one another.